# How do badge proposals work?

Tags: support, badges, badge-request

Who approves or creates new Stack Exchange badges and how do badge proposals work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Badge proposals work in much the same way as any other proposal for the site. A user suggests an idea for a badge, the community votes on it, and the team decides whether or not to implement it, after (presumably) looking at the proposal's popularity and merits.

Not all badges are created this way, of course. Most of the original badges were both conceived and implemented by the site's developers.